# Correct if/else statement syntax for django templates

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have a dating app and I need to create a link that is underneath each profile that a user matches on. Then, that link should pass their user id into the template so that messages are only displayed between the current user and that particular user based on the user id. I am having trouble here with the syntax of if/else statements within the Django template. How would I go about doing this?

**base.html/href messages link **

```
<li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'dating_app:messages' user.id %}">Check Messages</a>
                </li>
```

**models.py/InstantMessage**

```
class InstantMessage(models.Model):

    sender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name= 'sender',on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.message
```

**messages.html**

```
<div id="msg-list-div" class="panel-body">
        <ul id="msg-list" class="list-group">
            <br><br><br>
            {% for obj in messages %}
                {% if obj.sender == request.user and obj.receiver == profile%}

                    {% if obj.sender == request.user%}
                        <li class="text-right list-group-item">{{obj.message}}<br>{{ obj.date }}<li>
                    {% elif obj.receiver == profile %}
                        <li class="text-left list-group-item">{{obj.message}}<br>{{ obj.date }}<li>
                    {%endif%} 

                {%endif%}   
                {% empty %}
                    <li class="text-right list-group-item">No messages yet...Keep mingling!</li>
            {% endfor %}

        </ul>
</div>
```

**matches.html/ href link for messages.html**

```
<p><a href="{% url 'dating_app:messages' profile.id %}">chat</a></p>
```

**views.py/messages**

```
def messages(request, profile_id):
    messages = InstantMessage.objects.all()
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile,id=profile_id)

    return render(request, 'dating_app/messages.html', {'messages': messages,'profile':profile,})
```

**models.py**

```
class Profile(AbstractBaseUser):

    class Meta:
        swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'


    email                       = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email")
    username                    = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined                 = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login                  = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin                    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active                   = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff                    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    #what I added
    description                 = models.TextField()
    photo                       = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_photo',blank=False, height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100)
    matches                     = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='+', blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['description','photo','email']

    objects = ProfileManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self,app_label):
        return True


class UserVote(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    voter = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='given_vote', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vote = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user', 'voter'))


class InstantMessage(models.Model):

    sender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name= 'sender',on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.message
```

**entire models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser,BaseUserManager, User
from dating_project import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class ProfileManager(BaseUserManager):



    def create_user(self, username, email,description,photo, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("You must creat an email")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("You must create a username!")
        if not description:
            raise ValueError("You must write a description")
        if not photo:
            raise ValueError("You must upload a photo")

        user = self.model(
                email=self.normalize_email(email),
                username = username, 
                description= description,
                photo= photo,

            )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user 


    def create_superuser(self, username, email,description,photo, password):
        user = self.create_user(
                email=self.normalize_email(email),
                password=password,
                username=username,
                description=description,
                photo=photo,

            )

        user.is_admin=True
        user.is_staff=True
        user.is_superuser=True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user




class Profile(AbstractBaseUser):

    class Meta:
        swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'


    email                       = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email")
    username                    = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined                 = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login                  = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin                    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active                   = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff                    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    #what I added
    description                 = models.TextField()
    photo                       = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_photo',blank=False, height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100)
    matches                     = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='+', blank=True)



    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['description','photo','email']


    objects = ProfileManager()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin


    def has_module_perms(self,app_label):
        return True



class UserVote(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    voter = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='given_vote', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vote = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user', 'voter'))



class InstantMessage(models.Model):

    sender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name= 'senderr',on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.message
```

Comment: I would definitely try to send only the messages that match for the conversation, filtered from the model in the view. Don't make the template cycle through every message sent by every user of your app.

Comment: Also first inner if statement will always be true since the same condition is checked in the outer if `obj.sender == request.user`.

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested it is better to do all heavy work in a view, not in a template:

```
def messages(request, profile_id):
    messages = InstantMessage.objects.filter(sender=request.user, receiver_id=profile_id, )
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile,id=profile_id)
    ...
```

Imagine if `InstantMessage` contains billions of records - how fast would `InstantMessage.objects.all()` work? And for what reason.

And since you want to render "a chat", I guess you need something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q
...
    messages = InstantMessage.objects.filter(Q(sender_id=request.user.id, receiver_id=profile_id,) 
            | Q(sender_id=profile_id, receiver_id=request.user.id,) ).\
        values('sender_id', 'message', 'date', ).\
        order_by('date',)
```

*see also examples of making complex queries in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#or).*

and the template:

```
{% for msg in messages %}
    <li class="{% if msg.sender_id == request.user.id %}text-right{% else %}text-left{% endif %} list-group-item">
        {{ msg.message }}<br/>{{ msg.date }}
    </li>
{% empty %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error at where whatever  ' || '  symbol is called

Comment: def messages(request, profile_id):
    messages = InstantMessage.objects.filter(Q(sender_id=request.user.id, receiver_id=profile_id,) 
   || Q(sender_id=profile_id, receiver_id=request.user.id,) ).\
        values('sender_id', 'message', 'date', ).\
        order_by('date',)
   
    return render(request, 'dating_app/messages.html', {'messages': messages,})

Comment: sorry, it has to a single `|` there.

Comment: fixed that but now I'm getting a     'Exception Value: 
name 'Q' is not defined'

Comment: added required import to the answer

Comment: ok tried that and now I'm getting a 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.models''      I did make my own user model, not sure if that has anything to do with it

Comment: django.db.models

Comment: ok, so it's not correct. 1) The messages are not displaying for the request.user's message inbox, but only for the user that I messaged. The message they sent to me shows up in their inbox as well. 2) both sent and received messages show up only on one side rather than being separated

Comment: I guess this is data or parameters issue: `sender` and/or `receiver` contain not what you think or `profile_id` contains, for example, id of a different model than sender_id and/or receiver_id so they are incompatible. Print parameter values and run raw select queries in DB for debug purpose to ensure that everything is fine with them. Also your original view passes `profile` which is unnecessary - `profile_id` is fine. My template contains comparison with `profile_id` feel free to change it to `profile.id` or update your view.

Comment: Hmm, so I got it working to where the messages do appear on the correct sides by doing     '{% if msg.sender_id == request.user %}'.....  BUT the only problem is that the messages do not appear in the request.user's inbox, they only appear for other users.

Comment: Please update your question with message saving method/view/form/whatever.

Comment: Well, right now I'm just creating messages through the admin, I haven't made the form yet but I did add my entire models.py. Super weird, because whatever I do, I can't get it to work for request.user. I can only see other user's inboxes that I have already messaged as request.user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211517/discussion-between-rez-and-ivan-starostin).

Comment: Try adding `@login_required` decorator to the view `def messages`.

Comment: The problem with this is that it still doesn't display messages in MY user's inbox. It displays them correctly in another user's inbox between my user, and it only shows the messages between those 2 users rather than all the user's that my user has messaged. But, as I added an href link underneath each profile, whenever I hit that link, it uses request.user's PK and takes it to request.user's inbox which is empty. The only way I have gotten my user to display messages is by querying messages with ONLY request.user BUT then it displays ALL messages rather than just the ones between specific usr

Comment: As I said before, something is wrong with your data and/or parameters. Print or render `profile_id`, `request.user.id` and `sender_id` with `receiver_id` from each message you're expecting to show up on appropriate page. The issue is with message creation or with view parameterisation.